# How to make an url show it? ?id=1

Tags: php, url, sqlmap

I'm trying to create a simple site for local test, but I need to show on URL the following:

> ?id=1

How can I do it?

Comment: That's from a submitted from with the method get!

Comment: Look up how to create a querystring.

Comment: What? You could just echo it out, use `http_build_query`, build a form, or some other method that would be appropiate. Your question is quite vague about the context you need the string in.

Comment: I need it to run sqlmap tests. I have php login with mysql and some  other tables in database. But, to run sqlmap I need to use strings on URL like "?id=1" or something else.

Comment: If you're confused on this, would you even know what to do with that `id` once it's submitted?

Comment: You may find it easier, in the long run at least, to read through some tutorials, which will explain this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by hyperlink, form submit, manually typing it into the URL bar and many other methods. Use a hyperlink:

```
<a href="www.example.com?id=1">ID1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not too sure what you are asking, but if you are looking to add an id variable to the URL you need to add it to the URL when you redirect

EX. 
From link

`<a href="127.0.0.1/mysite/index.php?userid=1">Link</a>`